# Scientifically valid ways of naturally increasing breast size?

Tags: growth

I have read some stuff online about how to naturally increase your breast size. However, I don't know whether to believe it, because it looks commercial, so they have a good reason to hype it.

So I'm wondering if there are books or scientific papers or anything that is based on science, that explains what determines fluctuations in breast size (for women who are not in puberty or pregnant).

I'm assuming the only way to increase breast size while retaining a calorie neutral diet, is through anything that naturally influences certain hormones (in whatever way).

Is this something about which there are scientific answers?

Comment: Pregnancy is a naturally proven way to increase breast size, though it has other side effects too.

Comment: How is this a fitness question though.....?

Answer (score 1):

[Livestrong article](http://www.livestrong.com/article/421223-how-to-increase-breast-size-naturally-by-exercise-and-eating/), looks like the most legit thing on this subject. You can either get fatter (which isn't recommended, unless you're underweight of course) or you can get bigger pecs (which won't typically make much of a difference). I'd also point out better posture will make the most of what you've got, and that can be one of the results of regular exercise.

I think you're suggesting that some way of [naturally increasing estrogen](http://www.livestrong.com/article/354463-how-to-boost-estrogen-levels/) would help, which is after all the cause of breast growth during pregnancy. But I don't think there is one, unless you're currently underweight or something. Some people think soy helps with this. There's really no evidence for this, but soy is generally quite good for you, so try that if you want.

On the plus side, much more is possible with the lower body (if your goal is achieving the commonly desired female body type). I've heard Mark Rippetoe talk about a plastic surgeon acquaintance of his who does breast implants and then recommends his patients do a lot of squats.

Comment: Is estrogen the only hormone that increases breast size? I suppose testosterone also decreases breast size? does that mean if I train in the gym or do "agressive" things, I create testosterone and decrease my breast size?

Comment: @FitnessGirl testosterone itself doesn't decrease breast size. Excess testosterone will end up converted into estrogen and that will cause breast tissue growth even in men.

Answer (score 0):

> *I have read some stuff online about how to naturally increase your
>   breast size. However, I don't know whether to believe it, because it
>   looks commercial, so they have a good reason to hype it.*

If there were a “magic way” to increase breast size naturally considering the popularity of elective painful surgery – this would NOT remain a secret.

I don’t even know what it is but I’m going to guess it’s an unregulated herbal supplement.  Supplements are **NOT** reviewed by the FDA or any third party before you open take them - they frequently don’t contain the ingredients that are listed – or they’re simply labeled as a “proprietary blends”.